# node.js append meta data to json

Tags: node.js, metadata

I have a node.js api that pulls data from mongodb using mongoose and want to append some meta data to the returned json document.  What is the best way of doing this?

Current format of returned document

```
[
    {
    _id: "55edf1cc49f2dd46365b0884",
    title: "title 1",
    body: "body 1"
    },
    {
    _id: "55edfffe49f2dd46365b0885",
    title: "title 2",
    body: "body 2"
    }
]
```

Required format of returned document

```
{
    "data": [
        {
        _id: "55edf1cc49f2dd46365b0884",
        title: "title 1",
        body: "body 1"
        },
        {
        _id: "55edfffe49f2dd46365b0885",
        title: "title 2",
        body: "body 2"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "test": "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not a lot of information about your API. What framework are you using? What's the architecture of the api, do you have layers for routes, services, data access or is it just in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious solution would be this (assuming you're using Express):

```
res.json({
  data : mongooseResult,
  meta : { test : 'test' }
});
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, yes i'm using express.